# Wordpress - Twenty Fourteen Theme - Moving Featured Content Slider to Content Area

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the featured content slider provided as standard in the Twenty Fourteen Wordpress theme. It's doing pretty much everything I want it to do at this point and I have done some basic customisation on it using CSS, however after speaking to a few folk internally they are looking to "insert" this into the main content area of the page.

I've had a look around, and found a suggestion to change the index.php file to change the position of the PHP statement that registers the featured content. After making these changes to my child theme and publishing them nothing happened.

I am at a complete loss as to where to look next or what to change (without trial and error which could break everything!)

It's probably a very simple solution that I'm completely overlooking so apologies if this is the case. This is an internal site so I can't provide any links unfortunately. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Index.php current code:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">


    <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If  you     want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called     content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );


    <?php
                            if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
                                // Include the featured content template.
                                get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
                            }
    ?>
```

Further to this, the Featured Content is currently located at the top of the page and does not fit within the content and primary sidebars (it is positioned above the content sidebar to the right of the primary sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about breaking a live site, then you should make a copy of what you've got, and install it locally on your machine.

[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is very good for this, if you're running Windows, and makes your computer act like an Apache web server.

Moving on from that, it would be helpful if you could provide some code, showing where your featured content slider is positioned.

And also make sure you're editing the correct file for your theme.

Comment: I don't currently have access to set up anything like that on my domain PC, I have set up backups though, so can always revert if something goes majorly wrong! I have also put the code in main post though I'm not even sure I'm editing the right thing at this point.

Comment: You don't need the `<?php` at the start of the frontpage block, as the PHP line is already open. From the looks of it, this will place your featured content directly below the post/page content. Is that correct?

Comment: I have removed the second php tag (didn't notice that!), it isn't moving it's position at all from where it was before. It is still above the content on the page.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct page? If you add a line of text or an echo under `get_header()`, does it reflect that when viewing the site?

Comment: Oops, you are right, I was editing the wrong php file. Sorry about that. :(

Comment: Well, I want it under a piece of content, but below another piece of content, so I figured it was best to use he insert PHP addon, experimenting now, I am copying the code from Page.php where I want the PHP to execute but not seeing anything yet.

Comment: You should just be able to cut the code from the index page there, and put it into anywhere you want (page, loop, etc). You could then put it inside an IF statement based on the page ID. (Show it one place on one page, then another place on another page)

Comment: Weird, I've got it working now. There is a rendering issue by the looks of things though, it is showing a black box to the left of the featured content itself? And a new element called "p" displaying a small black box above it.

Comment: That could be down to the Wordpress editor adding html tags when you've got blank spaces. It seems your `p` elements have styling on them that make background black. Check your wordpress Pages content, and take out any unneccessary elements. (Tip: I actually prefer to disable the visual editor, and use simple HTML)

Comment: Yeah,I'll continue to look into this, the original issue has been solved though. Thank you a lot for your help! :)